# Can somebody be a Vaishnava and believe in Hari-Hara-abheda?

Tags: shiva, vaishnavism

The most commonly accepted definition of Vaishnavas is people who believe Lord Vishnu to be supreme. But can a person call himself a Vaishnava while believing in Hari-Hara-abheda? What do different Vaishnava Sampradayas say regarding this?

Comment: Shiva is considered to be Ardent Bhagavata acc. to Vaishnavam so there is no question of equality of Shiva with Bhagavan Vishnu acc. to Vaishnava Sampradayas

Comment: First we should define "who is Vaishnava"? If Vaishnava is the one who has Vishnu as Ista Deva, then he can consider Shiva is equal to Vishnu.

Comment: **The most commonly accepted definition of Vaishnavas is people who believe Lord Vishnu to be supreme** Where did u find this definition? Any scriptural quotes? A Shaiva is one whose Ishta Devata is Shiva and so on ..This is the definition... a (true) devotee will be a devotee irrespective of whether his Ishta is considered supreme or not..Such things don't even come to a true devotee's mind...Also this supremacy thing is more of a Kali Yuga and a regional thing..Don't tread such sinful paths that lead straight to hells..

Comment: In any case, there's a variety of definitions you can give for Vaishnava: 1. Having Vishnu as your Ishta Devata 2. Having Bhakti towards Vishnu 3. Believing that Vishnu is supreme 4. Following the Pancharatra Agamas.  I think definitions 3 and 4 make the most sense.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62683/discussion-on-question-by-surya-kanta-bose-chowdhury-can-somebody-be-a-vaishnava).

Comment: @ram and @ Rickross, i deleted all your comments. Please continue discussion in above chat room.

Comment: @Surya Kanta See the points 8 and 9 [here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16899/was-adi-shankaracharya-a-shaiva-or-a-vaishnava-what-were-his-views-on-shiva-and/16922#16922)

Comment: There is a story of Mother Lakshmi Worshipping Shiva when Vishnu becomes upset with Her . Then Shiva asks Her why do you worship me when Vishnu Himself is your consort? Then MahaLakshmi says I do not see any difference in Thee and Hari. Then Shiva says it is quite a wonder that you see no difference in Me and Him, this state is very rare, even the yogis are unable to not find difference in Me and Him. Then Shiva blessed her that Vishnu will come again, and Vishnu comes happy and  He and Lakshmi give birth to Haihaya.

Answer (score 9):

The Harivaṃśa has a stotra extolling both the similarity and unified form of Viṣṇu and Śiva. There are even several epithets dedicated to them: Hariharātmaka and Agniṣomātmaka.The following is an excerpt from a stotra from the Harivaṃśa (Viṣṇu-parva) extolling both Viṣṇu and Śiva as identical and Supreme Lords:

> *Chapter 125 - Battle between Śrī Kṛṣṇa and lord Śiva*
>
> 125.29 “Mārkaṇḍeya said—I offer my salutation to Śiva in the form of Viṣṇu, and Viṣṇu in the form of Śiva. **I find no difference between the two**. Observing my feelings, let both of them bestow welfare on me.”
>
> ... *(more praise and comparing)*
>
> 125.39 “The one who recites this stotra daily and the one who listen to it, he achieves te final beautitude by the grace of Viṣṇu and Rudra.”
>
> 125.40 “I shall offer prayer to Hari and Hara who are meeting Brahmā. **Both of them are the supreme lords**, besides being the creator and the destroyer of the world.”
>
> 125.41 “Lord Viṣṇu cannot exist without Śiva, and Śiva cannot exist without Viṣṇu. Therefore, in the earlier times, **both of them had unified personality**.”
>
> 125.42 “I offer my salutation to lord Rudra and Viṣṇu, who roam about in the world individually or collectively.”
>
> ... *(etc.)*

The Harivaṃśa (escpecially the Viṣṇu-parva) has been quoted by many Gauḍiya-Vaiṣṇava Ācāryas (according to Bhumipati Dasa) and has been mentioned as an important Vaiṣṇava scripture by both Caitanya Mahāprabhu (in his Śrī Caitanya Caritāmṛta [(source)](https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/madhya/23/116/)) and by his disciple Sanātana Gosvāmī (in his auto-commentary Dig-darśinī on his Śrī Bṛhad-bhāgavatāmṛta [(source)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brihad-bhagavatamrita/d/doc54068.html))

***Prologue***

The preceding context is interesting and in short relates that, Śiva, while protecting Bāṇāsura, was fighting a war with Śrī Kṛṣṇa. When Śiva was about to fire a weapon at Kṛṣṇa, Kṛṣṇa counter-attacked Śiva which overpowered him and he became over-exhausted.

After a while, the earth suffered greatly due to the effects of this battle and the earth-goddess (Dhāraṇī-devī) went to Brahmā for a solution:

> 125.14 “The Earth goddess said—O lord of gods, of valorous one, I am suffering from the great prowess. Having suffered considerably from the burden of lord Śiva, it appears that I shall have to submerge in the oceanic waters.”

Brahmā then meets with Śiva and utters his disapproval of the fighting, giving the first hint of his unity with Viṣṇu:

> 125.17: “I do not like your fighting with Śrī Kṛṣṇa - the valorous one. You are unable to understand Śrī Kṛṣṇa. In fact **your own soul has been divided into two**.”

After establishing this inseparable link (which no one was able to identify), Brahmā inquired the sage Mārkaṇḍeya for explaining the reason behind this aspect.

Mārkaṇḍeya’s answer is in the form of a stotra of which the above is an excerpt.

***The epithets:***

> 125.30 “The one who is the begining middle or end, who is indestructible and eternal being Akṣara—Brahma, his form is that of Hari-Hara of Brahman, I shall describe before you the same, **Hari Harātmaka**.”
>
> 125.35 “Rudra has also been known as the fire, while Viṣṇu has also been known as soma or the moon. Because of this, the entire universe, is also known as **Agniṣomātmaka**.”

Comment: "Both of them are the supreme lords" But there can be only supreme lord. People call that one lord with different names. How is it possible? How can two be supreme at the same time?

Comment: @SreeCharan How you can be son and friend at same time?

Comment: @TheDestroyer LOL. I am not a son when I am a freiend and not a friend when I am a son, References change when I am changing the character. When I try to be a son, the character of a friend decreases and vice versa. BTW, how is this related to the question I asked? This is not about an attribute. It is about supremacy means Paramatma means ultimate reality. There will be one. Not two or three. Paramatma is a monarch.

Comment: @SreeCharan You can be both Son and friend. You have same flesh in your body when you are both Son and friend. Do you look same when you are young and old? How do you expect Parabrahman to look same everytime? This is not said by me but by Vedas itself. "Ekam Sat Vipra Bahuda Vadanti". Those who limit Parabrahman to one attribute or one form, he is not seeing God everywhere.

Comment: @SreeCharan As mentioned in the answer, “both of them are the supreme lords”; this is because in the beginning, “both of them had unified personality”; so you ask, how is this possible? This is is possible because Brahmā states that their (unified) soul “has been divided into two”. Further on, Mārkaṇḍeya also states: “... The basic form of both of them is one and the same, because of the separation of their functions, they have been given the names of Rudra, Viṣṇu and Brahmā.”

Comment: @TheDestroyer Seeing god in everything and having calling many as supreme is different. Even when I look different with the change of the age, I am the same person. I feel the things which happen to the gross body like ours will not happen to him too. He is second to none. So, the brahman changes? How is it possible? He is the one and only and everlasting. It is said *Ekam* sat viprah Bahuda vadanti. It means the truth is/wiil be *one* and the wise men call  it with different names.  The names change but the supreme lord will be one. Not many.  EKAM EVA ADVITIYAM BRAHMA" Isn't it?

Comment: "EKAM EVA ADVITIYAM BRAHMA" means He is one without second it doesn't Contradict "Vipra Bahuda Vadanti" of RIgveda. Upanishads also say the same for Rudra replacing Brahman with Rudra.

Comment: How is this answering the question? "But can a person call himself a Vaishnava while believing in Hari-Hara-abheda? What do different Vaishnava Sampradayas say regarding this?" Can you summarize your answer in 1-2 lines at the end so that it's directly addressing some part of the question?

Comment: @sv. What you quote was added very recently in his edit, while I answered this question like almost two years ago... The original question contained this: “But can a person call himself a Vaishnava while saying Lord Shiva to equal to Lord Vishnu?” And as you can see I commented upon the equality between Viṣṇu and Śiva based on a Vaiṣṇava scripture. Anyway, it's not really fair to judge an old answer based on a recent edit, changing the question.

Comment: Ok, I see OP made some edits. "And as you can see I commented upon the equality between Viṣṇu and Śiva based on a Vaiṣṇava scripture" - can you expand this & add it directly to the answer? I don't see the connection between Vaishnava & Harivamsha in your answer.

Comment: @sv. I have added three references to prove vaishnava connection.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, a true Vaishnava do not differentiate between Lord Vishnu, Lord Shiva and Lord Brahma. It has been described by Lord Vishnu himself to Lord Brahma in **Padma Purana, Part 10, Section 7 (KRIYAYOGASARAKHANDA), Chapter 2**.

> Those who look upon you, me and Sankara as equal, and who honour a guest, should be known to be Visnu's devotees.
>
> Those who are free from devotion to heretics, who are highly devoted to Siva, who are engaged in (observing) the vow of Caturdasi, should be known to be Vais- navas.

In **Vishnu Purana 5.33.47-49**, it was said by Lord Krishna that only deluded person see difference in Me and Lord Shiva.

> त्वया यदभयं दत्तं तद्दत्तमग्विलं मया ।
>   मत्तो विभिन्नमात्मानं द्रष्ट्रं नार्हसि शंकर ।।
>   योऽहं स त्वं जगच्चेदं स देवासुरमानुषम् ।
>   अविद्यामोहितात्मानः पुरुषा भिन्नदर्शिन ।।
>
> That Abhaya which was given by you was also given by me. Oh Shankara do not see yourself different from me. That which is me the same is you, this entire creation, Devas, Manyushyas and Asuras. Only those who are deluded by Avidya see me and you as different.

Comment: Great addition from Vishnu Purana.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks, it was pointed out by Tezz.

Answer (score 4):

A true Vaishnava is a devotee of Vishnu. He sees Vishnu in everything.

So for him Shiva is Vishnu only. So, the question does not even arise in the mind of a true Bhakta.

From [the Kurma Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/kurmapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=12):

> **Krishna’s worship to Maha Deva :**
>
> Shri Krishna had Eight Principal Wives viz. Rukmini, Satyabhama,
>   Jambavati, Nagnajiti, Mitravinda, Lakshmana, Kalindi and Maadri, but
>   accepted sixteen thousand maidens released from the prisons of
>   Narakaasura whom he decimated. Rukmini had eight sons viz.
>   Charudeshna, Suchaaru, Chaaruvesha, Yashodhara, Chaarushrava,
>   Charuyasha, Pradyumna and Shankha. Similarly other wives had several
>   sons. But Devi Jambavati longed to get an  exemplary Son like Indra
>   and on realising this wish decided to perform Parama Tapasya to Parama
>   Shiva and left for the Ashram of Maharshi Upamanyu on the banks of
>   Ganges.
>
> ................
>
> Following the rules very strictly, Krishna followed  the ‘Upadesha’ or
>   the teachings and instructions of Upamanyu such as Paashupata Yoga,
>   Paashupata Vrata and Paashupata Jnaana and incessantly recited Rudra
>   Mantras with strict adherence of the formal and required form of 
>   worship  to Mahadeva. After considerable effort, Shri Krishna visioned
>   Maha Deva and Devi Parvati on the Sky as follows:
>
> Thus Krishna had a full ‘darshan’of Shiva accompanied by Parvati, Shri
>   Krishna applauded him as follows:
>
> Namostu tey Shashwata Sarvayoney Brahmaadhipam,
>
> Twaamrushayo vadanti,
>
> Tapascha Satwam cha Rajastamascha Twaameva Sarvam pravadanti Santah/
>
> Twam Brahmaa Hariratha Vishwayoniragnih Samhartaa Dinakara
>   mamdalaadhivaasah,
>
> Praanastwam Hutavaha Vaasavaadi bhedastwaamekam sharanamupaimi
>   Devameesham/
>
> Saamkhyaastwaam Vigunamathaahureka rupam Yogastwaam satatamupaasatey
>   hrudistham,
>
> Vedaastwaamabhidadhateeh Rudramagnim twaamekam sharanamu-  paimi
>   Devameesham
>
> ................
>
> My salutations to You Shaaswata! Sarva Mula Kaarana or the Root Cause
>   of the Totality; Rishis affirm that you are the Master of Brahma; they
>   assert that you are the Spring of the Three Gunas of
>   Satwa-Rajasa-Tamasas; indeed you are the one residing in all the Lokas
>   of Brahma, Vishnu, Vishwayoni, Agni, Samharta and also in Surya
>   Mandala; You are the varied Forms of Praana, Hutavaha or Agni, Indra
>   and all other Devaas; I have arrived into the shelter of Maha Deva;
>
> .................
>
> Yasyaseshavibhaaga- heenamamalam hridyantaraavasthitam
>
> Tatwam Jyotiranantamekamachalam Satyam Param Sarvagam,
>
> Sthaanam praahuranaadi madhyanidhanam yasmaadidam jaayatey
>
> Nityam twaahu –mupaimi Satyavibhavam Vishweswaram tam Shivam/
>
> Om Namo Nilakanthaaya Trinetraaya cha ramhasey,
>
> ....
>
> I seek shelter unto the truthfully glorified Vishweshwara Shiva, whom
>   Tatwajnas worship as he is Indivisible, Transparent, Existent in one’s
>   interiors of heart, Luminous, Infinite, Unique, Stable, Truthful,
>   All-Pervasive displayer of Beginning-Central-Terminating points of
>   Life. My sincere salutations to you Pranava Swarupa, Nilakantha,
>   Trilochana, Shakti Rupa, Maha Deva, Ishaana, Pinaaka dhanush dhaari,
>   Munda-Danda Dhaarana, Vajra hasta dhaarana, Digvastra, Kapardini or
>   Jataadhaari with Matted Locks; Bhairava naada, Kaala Swarupa;
>   Naagayajnopaveeta dhari (He who wears Serpents as the Holy Thread);
>   Agni samaana veerya nidhana (He whose semen is like Fire); Gireesha;
>   Swaahaakaara or of the Swarupa of Offerings to Agni in Homas; Mukta
>   -atthahaasa or  He whose maddening voice reverberates...

Maharshi Markandeya wondered as to why Krishna who himself was worship-worthy and granted boons to his devotees worships Shiva Lingam, Krishna replied smilingly:

> Markandeya! Whatever you said is in order and the Truth is that I am
>   worship-worthy by others; **but still I worship Ishaana**; there is
>   nothing that I cannot achieve a thing, nor is unavailable to me; **yet
>   I am aware that I perform Puja to Parama Shiva**. Those who are unable
>   to overcome Maya or Illusion could never achieve Shiva Darshana; **but
>   I  do realise that my foundation is Shiva and hence I always worship
>   Him.** There is no better Punya Phala nor fearlessness than what the
>   Sacred Task of Lingaarchana would confer and for accomplishing
>   propitiousness human beings must resort to Shiva Puja, Shri Krishna
>   affirms. Those who realise and experience Vedic Siddhaantaas
>   (Principles) **do  recognise that Shiva Linga is my own Swarupa and
>   that is precisely why I perform my own  worship of the Atma Swarupa of
>   Ishana, says Krishna. He further confirms: I am Shankara’s Parama
>   Murti and I am Shankara myself without doubt. Vedas have emphasised
>   that there is no difference whatsoever and Krishna and Shiva are just
>   the same**. This is the reason why that one should install Shiva Linga
>   all over

And [in  a different chapter](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/kurmapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=18) of the same Purana now Lord Shiva affirms the oneness of Shiva-Vishnu as follows:

In the context of the above, Maha Deva emphasised again as in earlier pages about the identity of himself and Vishnu Deva; this was necessary since a seperate ‘Ishwara Gita’in the current Kurma Purana sought to clarify that its contents were in no way contradictory ; even in the description of Shiva Tandava described above, Vishnu too was stated to have joined the Celestial Dance! Maha Deva thus confirmed as follows:

> Ayam Narayano yohameeshwaro naatra samshayah,
>
> Naantaram ye prapashyanti teshaam Devamidam param/
>
> Mamaushaa Paramaa Murtirnaaraayana samaahvayaa,
>
> Sarva Bhutaatmabhutasthaa Shantaa chaakshara sangjnitaa/
>
> Ye twanyathaa prapashyanti lokey bheda drusho janaah,
>
> Na tey maam samprapashyanti jayentey cha punah punah/
>
> Yetwimam Vishnu – mavyaktam maam vaa Devam Maheswaram,
>
> .......
>
> That Narayana is Ishwara that is me undoubtedly. There is indeed no
>   difference between us and he too is to be worshipped. Narayana is
>   ‘Shaanti-Akshara’ imprinted in every body’s heart. Some imagine
>   otherwise that we are figured other wise and they continue to get into
>   the cycle of birth and death and could never ever attain Mukti. Those
>   who visualise me and Narayana as just the same would have no rebirth.
>   As such, Vishnu has no beginning or end as in my case, meaning thereby
>   we are both the same. Those who confuse Vishnu as another Deva would
>   for sure reach Narakas. Those who are my bhaktaas being either
>   Murkhaas or Stupids, Panditas or Learned Vidvans or even untouchables
>   should indeed have the possibility of Mukti, provided they do not 
>   dislike or distrust him. Hence my  bhaktaas ought to perform puja to
>   Vishnu with all humilty and belief.) Then both Vishnu and Shiva
>   disappeared simultaneously, stated Vyasa Muni.

Thus both Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu (in the form of Krishna) affirm the one-ness of Shiva-Vishnu in the same Purana. So, you can verily be the devotee of one God and see the other God just as another form of your Ishta (favorite Deity).

To sum up, i am quoting  few verses from an Agama called Nila Tantra, which is part of another major Agama called Vishnu KrAnta:

> TAvat Tantre Bhedabuddhi Stavadeva Prithak KriyA | Harihare
>   BhedabuddhirjAyAte Jagadambike ||
>
> KarAlavadana KAli Srimadekajata ShivA | Shodashi Bhairavi BhinnA
>   BhinnA Cha Bhuvaneswari ||
>
> ..........
>
> [Lord Shiva says] As long as Bhedabuddhi ( the feeling of dvaita or
>   duality) is there, the rituals and methods are different for different
>   devotees. [Then] There appear differences between Hari (Vishnu) and
>   Hara (Shiva). It appears [then] as if KAli, TArA (Ekajata), Shodashi,
>   Bhairavi are different different...
>
> **Nila Tantram 22-9.11**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62806/discussion-between-lakshminarayanan-and-the-destroyer).

Comment: That is why madhwa charya stressed more on taratamya.. if you accept equality like socialism the whole stack of devata will fall, we can  very well say since Ramakrsihna is brahman he is superme he is Vishnu  he is siva.. There is no doubt in the fall person to andhamas if one is sincerely following adv..