# Is it forbidden in any scripture for Vaishnavas to refrain from non-vegetarian and stimulant foods?

Tags: vaishnavism, non-vegetarian

Most Vaishnavas refrain from meat and stimulant foods. But is this compulsory by the scriptures? Do any of the scriptures forbid Vaishnavas to take meat and stimulant foods?

Comment: It's not compulsory. You can eat meat based on your Varna or work.

Comment: See Ahara Niyama grantha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Vaishnavism* is a *sampradAya* (sect or doctrine). Anyone who believes in [the supremacy of] lord Vishnu or loves lord Vishnu, can become a *Vaishnava*. That person can belong to any of the castes from the 4 divisions: *Brahmana, Kshatriya, Vaishya or Shudra*:
[What are the qualities of a Vaishnava according to the scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20335/1049)

Meat eating is altogether a different ball game. It has to do with person's nature & food habits. Hence, **relating meat eating and *Vaishnavism* is not proper**.
e.g. Krishna was a form of Vishnu, Arjuna truly loved & surrendered to Krishna, then Arjuna can be termed as Vaishnava [in theory]. Being a Kshatriya, Arjuna could have consumed meat.

---

According to following thread, "meat eating" itself may not be sin if done under right circumstances:
[How to wash away sin after unconsciously consuming non-vegetarian food?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20467/1049)

And according to following post, in today's time everyone has a moral responsibility to avoid "meat eating" (especially Brahmana-s):
[Should a Brahmin be vegetarian?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8206/1049)

Comment: Anyone who believes in the supremacy of lord Vishnu, can become a Vaishnava.---- This definition is non existent in scriptures. Its not the correct definition of Vaishnava. One who loves Vishnu (or one who's a devotee of Vishnu) is a Vaishnava.

Comment: Vaishnavism is not a doctrine. It is a sect formed by the teachings of Pancharatra Agamas. "Anyone who believes in the supremacy of lord Vishnu, can become a Vaishnava" this definition is a perfect notion. A person who is initiated with the Vaishnava rituals is a Vaishnava. This is said by both Lord Vishnu and Shiva and the characteristic marks of a Vaishnava are also said. Check Padma Purana, Uttara Khanda. By this ritual, a devotee takes surrender (accepts him as supreme). So, don't agree when someone says this definition is non-existent in scriptures, don't take it seriously.

Comment: @Sinister Surrendering to a Deity and that Deity being supreme among all Deities- These are not anyway the same.  "Anyone who believes in the supremacy of Lord Vishnu, can become a Vaishnava."  This definition is not present in any scriptures, may be present in some acharyas work

Comment: @Sinister Yeah there are some trolls which are not meant to be taken seriously. No matter what you do they will oppose traditional system of vedantacharyas and great bhagwatas.