# Where in the Padma Purana are these verses located?

Tags: vaishnavism, caste-system, identification-request, padma-purana

Where in the Padma Purana are the following verses located?

> Na śūdrā bhagavad-bhaktās te tu bhāgavatā matāḥ
>   Sarva-varṇeṣu te śūdrā ye na bhaktā janārdane
>
> A devotee should never be considered a śūdra. All the devotees of the Supreme Personality of Godhead should be recognized as bhāgavatas. If one is not a devotee of Lord Kṛṣṇa, however, even if born in a brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya or vaiśya family, he should be considered as a śūdra.
>
> Sva-pākam iva nekṣeta loke vipram avaiṣṇavam
>    vaiṣṇavo varṇo-bāhyo ’pi punāti bhuvana-trayam
>
> If a person born in a brāhmaṇa family is not a vaiṣṇava, a non-devotee, one should not see his face, exactly as one should not look upon the face of a caṇḍāla, or dog-eater. However, a Vaiṣṇava found in varṇas other than brāhmaṇa can purify all the three worlds.
>
> śūdraṁ vā bhagavad-bhaktaṁ niṣādaṁ śva-pacaṁ tathā vīkṣate
>    jāti-sāmānyāt sa yāti narakaṁ dhruvam
>
> One who considers a devotee of the Supreme Personality of Godhead who was born in a family of śūdras, niṣādas or caṇḍālas to belong to that particular caste certainly goes to hell.

Source: Purport section of [this](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/antya/16/29) website.

Comment: I think this is present in the Uttara Khanda which is the most interpolated part of the Padma Purana.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury What makes you think that it is interpolated? Because many things are not acceptable to non Vaishnavas? :D

Comment: @Sinister There are some verses spoken by Lord Shiva in the Uttara Khanda that does not match what Lord Vishnu says in the Kriyayogasagara Khanda. For example, Lord Shiva in the Uttara Khanda says whoever thinks any other Gods to be equal to Lord Vishnu is a Pasandi while Lord Vishnu says that His true devotees see Vishnu and Shiva to be equal in the Kriyayogasagara Khanda. See Triyugi Narayan Mani's answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/what-are-the-qualities-of-a-vaishnava-according-to-the-scriptures/20338#20338

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury I think I already explained the meaning when Vishnu says Shiva or other Gods to be equal.  Vishnu is the antaryami of Shiva, Brahma etc., So, one should not censure the Vaishnavas and in that sense, they are equal. Same if you get Sayujya mukti.. But Vishnu himself is the creator, preserver, destroyer of the universe.  We should respect them. What Vishnu and Shiva both spoke is true. In fact Vishnu speaks of the ritual Samashrayanam. If one undergoes it, one should not worship others. It is there in the Pancharatra agamas too.

Comment: @Sinister Hey wait, isn't Samashrayanam the ritual done by Vadakalais?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury [We will continue discussion in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism).

Comment: @Ajay the first verse is in Hari Bhakti Vilas

Answer (score 5):

A partial answer and Giving source for the following verse.

> śva-pākam iva nekṣeta loke vipram avaiṣṇavam 
>   vaiṣṇavo varṇo-bāhyo ’pi punāti bhuvana-trayam
>
> In the world one should not look at a brāhmaṇa who is not a devotee of Viṣṇu as (one does not look at) a candala. Viṣṇu's devotee, even if he is outside the castes, purifies the three worlds. [**Padma Purana Uttara Khanda Chapter 224 Verse 53.**]

It should be noted that this is said by Lord Shiva to Parvati and by Vaiṣṇava, Shiva explicitly states that a Vaiṣṇava is one who has *the markings of a conch and disc of Viṣṇu* and not the others. So, by following this definition Vaiṣṇava is one who carries the conch and disc of Viṣṇu and one who worships Viṣṇu alone (These are words of Lord Viṣṇu himself). So, the notion of saying one who considers Viṣṇu as supreme or worships Viṣṇu alone is a Vaiṣṇava is from the scriptures itself and the words of God.

Comment: So, it means just because I am a worshiper of Shiva, even though I am a dwija brahmana, @Surya Kanta Bose Chowdhury(vaishnava) shouldn't see my face?

Comment: @Ajay Why did SuryaKanta Chowdhury come in middle? Is he initiated with the ritual? To answer your question, All should worship Vishnu. All should be Vaishnavas. Vaishnavas don't hate all other Gods.  They are submitted to Vishnu for hteir life. It means accepting Him as father, mother, protector, husband etc., So, they won't accept others as supreme and Gods. They see them as devatas.

Comment: Surya Kanta Bose Chowddhury is a Vaishnava. So, for example I used his name

Comment: @Ajay I gave the definition of a Vaishnva in my answer given by Vishnu and Shiva in the Padma Purana who is a Vaishnava. According to that, worshipping Vishnu alone is the first and the most important one. Respecting other Gods is also a duty of Vaishnava. A vaishnava should not see a face of ones who doesn't worship or disrespect Vishnu. That is the meaning. For eg: we don't talk or see the face of one who censures our father, mother.

Comment: @Sinister You mean the Samashrayanam ritual?

Comment: @Ajay These kind of words like- **"One should not look at a Brahmana who is not Vishnu devotee."**, **"Brahmana who does not worship ShivaLinga goes to hell and born as Shudra."**, "**A non-worshipper of Devi goes to hell, and has to take birth again and again.**", **"Do not give food to a Brahmana who has no knowledge. One who gives food even a grain more than necessary to survive, to such Brahmana, looses all his Upnyas."** – All these kind of **over-exaggerations** are found throughout literature. This are only affirmed assertions, but are not necessary.

Comment: @Ajay Just think- if you are Brahmana and do not worship Shiva, because you are a Vaishnava Brahmin, then would you really go to Hell. No. These assertive speech is found throughout literature. You have to take only that part which is the pure essence of true devotion. Do not give heed to such verses. These kind of verses are used to create firm belief of devotee in his/her God, and thus creating firm and utmost devotion.

Comment: @AnuragSingh In which scripture is said *Brahmana who does not worship ShivaLinga goes to hell and born as Shudra.*? Thanks.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Sorry I made mistake. It was that he goes to hell, but does not become a Shudra. in 35th Chapter, 9th book, Devi Puraanam, DharmaRaaja Yama tells Saavitri about various sins and hells. In that chapter-भक्त्या न पूजयेद्विप्रः शिवलिङ्‌गं च पार्थिवम् ॥ १५ ॥ स याति शूलिनः पापाच्छूलप्रोतं सुदारुणम् । स्थित्वा शताब्दं तत्रैव श्वापदः सप्तजन्मसु ॥ १६ ॥ ततो भवेद्देवलश्च सप्तजन्म ततः शुचिः ।

Comment: @brahmajijnasa A Brahmana who does not worship the Paarthiva ShivaLingam with devotion goes to the terrible hell full of Trishools called the "ShoolaProta" hell, because of this sin he committed. Then he remains in that hell for 100 years. After this, he becomes a 4-legged animal for seven births. After this, he becomes a Devala Brahmin for seven births. Only after this, he is free of his sin.