# What is the position of Lord Vishnu in the different 'Vaishnava' sects?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, gaudiya-vaishnavism

According to the dictionary meaning, a 'Vaishnava' is necessarily a 'Worshipper of Vishnu'.

> वैष्णव a. (-वी f.) [विष्णुर्देवतास्य तस्येदं वा अण्] 1 Relating to Viṣṇu; गां गतस्य तव धाम वैष्णवम् R.11.85. -2 Worshipping Viṣṇu. -वः 1 One of the three important modern Hindu sects, the other two being Śaiva and Śākta sects

I have found some people brand Sri Vishnu' as a 'Demi-God' while calling  themselves 'Vaishnavas'! Reference : http://www.krishna.com/info/demigods

What is the position of Lord Vishnu in the different 'Vaishnava' sects?

Comment: This is a 'fundamental' question and so may get many downvotes.

Comment: At your reputation, downvotes should hardly be your concern :)

Comment: [What are the qualities of a true Vaishnava?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20335/277) may be useful.

Comment: @commonman now question sounds better.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here

There is a sect of Hinduism who considers Krishna to be supreme brahman (godhead) based on SrimadBhagavatha's `krishnastu bhagavan swayam`. So the three moortis i.e., Brahma, Vishnu and Mahaeshwara merely work under the orders of `Krishna`. This is clearly expressed in the article and demigod also essentially mean the same.

However, these people also differentiate the trimoorthi vishnu with MahaVishnu who is none other than Krishna himself. They do believe in MahaVishnu so they are Vaishnavas.

Comment: So they must be 'Mahavaishnavas' instead of 'Vaishnavas' as per your logic!

Comment: @Abhijith Does this Maha-Vishnu corresponds to the Narayan from the Puratan Nar-Narayan. As I have read various references where Arjun-Krishna are said to be the Nar-Narayan, and even Bramha puts them in highest regards.

Comment: You have to cite some references for your answer.

Comment: Quoting Adi Shankaracharya commentary on Sri Vishnu Sashranamam. `kascha ashcha eeshwarashcha vibhutayaha keshavaha` meaning Brahma, Vishnu and Eshwara are vibhuti of Keshava.

Comment: What is the authenticity of Vishnu sahasranama bhashya being penned by Adi Shankaracharya?