# What are the qualities of a bhakt of Bhagwan?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhakti

What are the qualities of bhakt of Bhagwan (devotee of God) ? With particular emphasis on Vishnu or Krishna , Can anyone answer the question ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the qualities of a true Vaishnava?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/what-are-the-qualities-of-a-true-vaishnava)