# Did Ramanuja comment on Brahma Vaivarta Purana?

Tags: ramanujacharya, brahma-vaivarta-purana

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_Vaivarta_Purana

> The text is notable for identifying Krishna as the supreme Reality and asserting that all gods such as Vishnu, Shiva, Brahma, Ganesha are same, and all are incarnations of Krishna.

This might have been added after Ramanuja's time.  Since Vishnu Purana says Krishna is a part of a part of Vishnu, Ramanuja would have had issues with elevating Krishna to supremacy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ramanujacharya didn't write a commentary on the Brahma Vaivarta Purana. In fact Ramanujacharya didn't write any Purana commentaries at all.  As described in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/DViX) from Vedanta Desikan's Rahasyatraya Sara, he only composed nine works: the Sri Bhashya, the Vedanta Dipa, and the Vedanta Sara, three commentaries on the Brahma Sutras; the Bhagavad Gita Bhashya, a commentary on the Bhagavad Gita; the Vedartha Sangraha, an independent exposition of Visistadvaita; the Sharanagati Gadyam, the Sri Ranga Gadyam, and the Vaikuntha Gadyam, three prose hymns in praise of Vishnu; and the Nityam, a work about the daily activities of Sri Vaishnavas. (All these works are available in English except the Nityam.). He didn't compose commentaries on any Puranas including the Vishnu Purana.

Other Sri Vaishnava Acharyas did write Purana commentaries, but only on the Vishnu Purana and Srimad Bhagavatam as far as I know.  But Ramanujacharya does quote from the Brahma Vaivarta Purana, in [this section](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48510.htm) of the Sri Bhashya:

> Scripture declares, 'no work the fruits of which have not been completely enjoyed perishes even in millions of aeons.'

As [this forum post](http://www.ramanuja.org/sv/bhakti/archives/mar2002/0133.html) says, this verse is from the Prakriti Kanda of the Brahma Vaivarta Purana.

But Ramanujacharya does not quote or discuss the Brahmvaivarta Purana declaring Krishna to be supreme and Vishnu to be an incarnation of Krishna.  Whereas he and numerous other Sri Vaishnava Acharyas discuss the Shaiva Purana passages declaring Shiva to be supreme.

Comment: so krishna being supreme is a non-issue for non-gaudiya vaishnavites?

Comment: @SK Sri Vaishnavas certainly disagree with Gaudiya Vaishnava beliefs that Vishnu was an incarnation of Krishna.  I was more saying that the fact that they don't discuss such passages suggests that those passages are interpolations.

Comment: this "interpolation" argument is lowering the quality of contributions to the site.  nether sankara nor ramanuja referred to srimad bhagavatam.  what does that prove? the only way to prove interpolation is through linguistics, context (like reference to 4 castes in the late 10th mandala of rig veda - and also  rig veda mocks brahmins by likening brahmin pupils reciting their lessons to frogs croaking) and anachronistic historical references.

Comment: I have a theory that narayana-vishnu is southern and krishna (who subsumed vasudeva) hindi belt/bengali.  I suspect few divyadesams are dedicated to krishna @keshav srinivasan

Comment: @SK That argument sounds leftist. There are so many Vishnu temples in the North.

Comment: @SK And also check this out: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19746/why-did-ramanujacharya-adi-shankaracharya-never-refer-to-the-srimad-bhagavatam/19761#19761

Comment: @SK yes, westerners claim that purusha sukta is interpolation just like they say how ganesha is, or ramyana is where rama is Vishnu, or how bhagvad geeta is, or how badrayana and vyasa are different people. The scholars are crazy people, there are other mentions of purusha in rig Vedic brahmanams and even samhita, how can it be interpolation.

Comment: @SK Btw Gaudapada (the Guru of Shankara's Guru) referred to Srimad Bhagavatam implying the Bhagavatam existed during Shankara's time.