# Why Srimad Bhagavatam is not mentioned by Sri Ramanujacharya, Sri Yamunacharya and Sri Adi Shankaracharya. Why is that. Vaishnava answer pls

Tags: puranas, advaita, upanishads, dvaita

Why Srimad Bhagavatam is not mentioned by Sri Adi Shankaracharya,  Sri Yamunacharya or Sri Ramanujacharya

Comment: A partial answer is in this post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19746/why-did-ramanujacharya-adi-shankaracharya-never-refer-to-the-srimad-bhagavatam

Comment: It is barely thousands of years old. It didn't exist during Shankara's time I guess.

Comment: Sri Shankara does not generally quote from puranas. Only very rarely does he quote (from puranas like Vishnu purana).

Comment: It was because it had a lot of contradictions with Mahabharata. Therefore it has been a lot commented upon, still due to the heavy contradictions, they aren't reconciled to Mahabharata. Except for a few sects, others don't consider it at par other puranas.

Answer (score 0):

Remember about 400 works are attributed to Sankara...Not all are the works of Adi-Shankara

The reason is simple Sankara, Ramanujaa, etc were Vedantist.

Vedanta doesn't consider Purana as (main) Parmana, it's Vedas.

Sankara was quite strict with Vedas in his works hence he used smritis very less.

Or maybe there was no Bhagvata Puran during Sankara's era... (some say that)!!!

And Ramunja has used Vishnu puran to consider Sri Vishnu supreme.

Comment: Why did Samkara use Mahaharata then?

Comment: @SaffronVajra well i never said that he has not used the Smritis.I stated that he has used it very less..... BTW...here by smritis i mainly meant Purans as that is what we are talking about.